# Loop / infinite ScrollView React-Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I create this structure and I don't know how I can make my 1st ScrollView to loop or become infinite when I scroll to bottom or if I scroll up. I need this loop/infinite scroll to work on iOS and Android.

```
    render() {
      return (

        <ScrollView style={styles.paddingTop}>
          <View style={styles.testeDois}>
            <View style={styles.cardHome}>
              <Text>
                Home Carde
              </Text>
            </View>
            <ScrollView
              style={styles.size}
              automaticallyAdjustInsets={false}
              horizontal={true}
              decelerationRate={0}
              snapToInterval={CARD_WIDTH/3}
              snapToAlignment="start"
            >
              <View style={styles.card}>
                <Text>Card 1</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.card}>
                <Text>Card 2</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.card}>
                <Text>Card 3</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.card}>
                <Text>Card 4</Text>
              </View>
            </ScrollView>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      )
    }
  }
```